# TYPO3 8 - get extbase repository items in other languages

Tags: repository, typo3, extbase

This is basically the same problem as this but now for TYPO3 8 :
[get TYPO3 Extbase Repository items in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395809/get-typo3-extbase-repository-items-in-other-languages)

The workaround(s) mentioned in https://forge.typo3.org/issues/45873 did not work
in v8 for me. It return always the item in the default language.

Does anyone have a proper example that works?

```
    public function findTranslation($obj, $languageUid){
        $query = $this->createQuery();

        $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                $query->equals("l10n_parent", $course->getUid()),
                $query->equals("sys_language_uid",$languageUid)
            )
        );

    $result = $query->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

**what i tried**

temporarily overwrite the TCA languageField in repository

```
    public function findTranslation($obj, $languageUid){
        $query = $this->createQuery();

        $languageField = $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_extensionname_domain_model_table']['ctrl']['languageField'];
        unset($GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_extensionname_domain_model_table']['ctrl']['languageField']);

        $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                $query->equals("l10n_parent", $course->getUid()),
                $query->equals("sys_language_uid",$languageUid)
            )
        );


        $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_extensionname_domain_model_table']['ctrl']['languageField'] = $languageField;

        $result = $query->execute();
        return $result;
}
```

this workaraound found at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/45873

```
        $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_extensionname_domain_model_table']['ctrl']['transOrigPointerTable'] = '';
```

This hack found at forge.typo3.org/issues/45873#note-27 (CustomDataMapper)

Comment: Here an extension to test it:

https://github.com/kusiboss/extbaselanguagetest

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea, but if I remove the line `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_extensionname_domain_model_table']['ctrl']['languageField'] = $languageField;` from your code, the result is as expected