# Extbase language issue with not translated objects

Tags: extbase, typo3-8.x

We're currently unable to find a solution of Extbase doing not what we would expect.

In the Controller we have this:

```
$referenz = $this->referenzRepository->findByUid($this->settings['zentrum']);
```

This returns the object as expected. Now, there are two other languages where not everything is translated and should not appear on the translated page. The second dataset should not be outputted in the translation, because it is not translated:

[image]

Yet it is outputted in the default language. We have these global variables set and can not change these for different reasons.

```
config.sys_language_mode = ignore
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

We tried a custom function to return the object, but there is no output at all:

```
public function findReferenzByUid($uid)
{
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(false);
    $result = $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->equals('uid', intval($uid)),
            $query->equals('sys_language_uid', $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid)
        )
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

How could we accomplish this? The problem is that these are objects within another object. The "mother" object is translated, which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your custom function is the PID missing. You can try this:

```
$querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
$querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);

// new Storage IDs
$querySettings->setStoragePageIds(array(1, 26, 989));
```

Comment: or maybe this is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395809/get-typo3-extbase-repository-items-in-other-languages